# Thermal Expansion and Stress in a Heated Beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, beam, solid-mechanics

Consider the case of a beam that is supported in such a way that expansion can occur freely. Suppose that the beam is heated in such a way that the temperature varies with the depth of the beam. Let $T1$ be the temperature at the top and $T2$ be the temperature at the bottom $(T1 > T2)$. As a result, there will be unequal thermal expansion. Will there be any stress in the beam? Will the stress vary? I think stress should be present because if the top is expanding more than the fiber below it, then the fiber below it will try to oppose this. 
Additionally, will the beam bend? What happens to the case if the beam is not allowed to expand freely? In that case, I believe that the stress will be greater compared to the previous case where the beam can expand freely.

Comment: Is temperature difference used to fit larger pins into smaller holes? ie soaking things in liquid nitrogen...

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, maybe. What are you trying to say?

Comment: If the temperature distribution is linear across the section, the beam will just bend (if not restricted) and stress will be 0.

Comment: @TomášLétal Could you explain why the beam is bending and the reason for 0 stress?

Comment: @CrystalTerry When beam straight beam with constant section bends due to constant bending moment, axial strain has linear distribution across the section. Same strain distribution can be achieved using linear temperature distribution, so stress is not needed for equilibrium.

Comment: Thermal gradients alone cause strains, not stresses.  Stresses are only caused when the part is forced to be in a position that's not its natural or equilibrium state. Eg if you tried to bend the heated beam back into being straight